# Require Multiple Addresses in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

At our company we are trying to make it so that we require all customers to have a non-PO Box address on file. The address does not have to necessarily be a shipping or billing address. We still want customers to have the ability to enter in a PO Box address however. How would we go about setting this up?

So far this is what I have, but I am unsure what to check for.

```
    public function checkPhysicalAddressOnFile(){
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        foreach ($customer->getAddress() as $address) {
            if (stripos($address, '[p.o. box|p.o box|po box|po. box| pobox|post office box]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
if(preg_match("(?i)^\\s*((P(OST)?.?\\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\\s+(B(IN|OX))?)|B(IN|OX)", $address)){
    //This is a po box
}
else{
    //This is not
}
```